# Creating multi-word search suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

Can Elasticsearch's `edgen_n_grams` be set up in a way that will build multi-word phrases as ES indexes crawled data?

I'd like to use those multi-word phrases as search suggestions for a small search app that I'm building.

I'm using Nutch to crawl some sites and using ES to index the crawled data.

I figured that since ES can split on split on `whitespace` - that this shouldn't be that hard... however, I'm not getting the results I expected. So now I'm asking if this is even possible to do?

My ES index is setup like this

```
    PUT /_template/autocomplete_1
{
  "template": "auto*",
  "settings": {
   "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1   
    },
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "30",
          "token_chars": ["letter","digit","whitespace"]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
            ]     
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "anchor": {
          "type": "string"
        },
       "boost": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
       },...
```

`"content"` is the html body field per Nutch. I'm using 'content' as I figured it would generate the most phrases.

Comment: For creating multi-word phrases you need [shingles](https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-with-shingles), but I'm not sure what kind of autocomplete you need. Do you have a sample document and a sample search text?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, something to the effect of searching for a movie title like "the fast and the furios" or "fast 5" or "fast five" and the search query would be "f" - I'm reading up on shingles now

Comment: @AndreiStefan, I think this is exactly what I've been looking for! Put the info into an answer and I will accept it, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating multi-word phrases you need [shingles](https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-with-shingles). More specifically, [this token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) that can combine tokens.